# Where can I find some good open source Android games to accelerate the learning process?

Tags: android

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840231/open-source-examples-of-well-designed-android-applications) lists some good links to general Android applications (that I'm already looking over) but I'm interested at the moment in specifically games (board-type, intelligent games rather than action - in other words, I don't need real-time).

What are the best sources for applications like that? I want to look over the source code to get myself up to speed quickly.

(Please don't just Google for results, I've already done that and the pickings are a little scarce. I'm interested in anyone who's actually taken time to find and evaluate good sites for this - so ideally, you'd already be an Android developer interested in developing games).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16148638/602018

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code for my android game robotic space rock can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/monolithandroid

It is a block game with 3d opengl/es graphics, a highscore table, sound and midi music.

Comment: @Jalle I'd say that's a bit harsh, if not simply rude. Perhaps you could tell him what you didn't like about the game and provide some constructive criticism, without the "worst game ever" remarks.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a tip from someone who just started with Android games. The sample games that are in the SDK are good, however I've found it **FAR** easier (and better for learning) to start from scratch with a new Android Project rather than trying to modify an existing one. I ran into many dead ends using the "modify" approach. When I started from scratch I learned far more and got further faster with a blank slate.

Also, since you're not doing action games - don't get caught up in the games like JetBoy that use a thread to run the game loop. Threads certainly have their place, but if you're just learning they muddy the waters greatly.

Comment: Possibly good point about the threads but I have no fear of those concepts, I've been threading since Moses was a young lad :-) Having read the Android guidleines about responsiveness I'll probably use threads if only to ensure that dreaded "Close Application?" box doesn't appear. Thanks for the advice about the problems you had modifying instead of creating.

Answer (score 6):

You have a wast listing here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_Android_applications#Games

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of games in this list, which come with source: http://groups.fsf.org/wiki/LibrePlanet:LibrePlanetItalia/replicant#List_of_fully_free_android_applications

Comment: I think this is the new url: http://trac.osuosl.org/trac/replicant/wiki/ListOfKnownFreeSoftwareApps

Comment: this is simple game for implment java http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androidBallGame/TheHardestGame.zip

Answer (score 2):

we are maintaining a list of fully free software (gpl, apache and so on) applications for android and we have some games too.

Have a look here:

http://trac.osuosl.org/trac/replicant/wiki/ListOfKnownFreeSoftwareApps

The list is for a project called Replicant that aims to provide a fully free software android os with a fully free software market application (google market is not free libre software).

We will have a repository of fully free software applications too.

If you wish to help us, come to visit our irc channel on irc.freenode.net called #replicant

Thank you.